# library not loading in R

Tags: r, package, forecasting

```
library("forecast")
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'forecast', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: 4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.2.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
```

Comment: Update your R version and your package. Then try again please

Comment: @Pascal I already updated my R version and packages.

Comment: Why are you writing to me?

Comment: Why the warning about version of R if you have updated version?